# Bitwise operators usage

Tags: apex

I never see any code using these bitwise operators with boolean variables (being a and b a boolean variable):

```
 a | b

 a & b

 a ^ b
```

From what I understand, they could respectively replace:

```
 a || b

 a && b

 (a && !b) || (!a && b)
```

I find this interesting and useful, specially the last use case. Why people does not use these operators in their apex code?

Comment: I have used the exclusive or operator in my code quite recently in fact. That said, this question seems purely opinion based/speculative, which is not a great fit for this site.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The question may be somewhat opinion-based, but the answer can be framed in a non-opinionated way (I'm writing one now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is not the same as `||`, nor is `&` the same as `&&`.

The doubled-up versions are *shortcut operators*. This means that if the left-hand value evaluates to `true` or `false`, respectively, the other side is not evaluated. This means that CPU time is saved, and potential side effects can be reduced.

For example, look at these two pieces of code:

```
if(!getAuthToken() || !doCalloutWithToken()) {
```

versus

```
if(!getAuthToken() | !doCalloutWithToken()) {
```

The latter version will attempt to do the callout, even if the token was not acquired to begin with, meaning it has no chance of success.

The shortcut operators avoid this problem by not calling the right-hand side (RHS) of the operator if the left-hand side (LHS) would make the condition true or false by Boolean logic, regardless of the RHS.

As a more common example, consider:

```
String[] values;
if(values != null & values.size() > 0) {
```

This would throw a NullPointerException, because the RHS is evaluated needlessly. The more usual way to do this would be:

```
String[] values;
if(values != null && values.size() > 0) {
```

Which avoids the NullPointerException when the variable is null.

*Note: I'm specifically excluding `?.` from this example, which would be preferable, as it's unrelated to the topic at hand.*

This means that, for the majority of use cases, the shortcut operators are *almost* always the preferred version.

There are at least several use cases where you'd want to use `&`, `|`, and `^`, but these come up very infrequently in business logic, mostly because we don't need to know the "full" result, as we can quit early when we recognize that continuing an operation is impossible.

You'd normally use these operators to write and/or write bits to a bitfield, or sometimes you want to accumulate a true/false value to see if an operation completed successfully (I find myself often using `&=`, for example, which is shorthand for `x = x & y`).

As for the XOR operator (`^`) specifically, it is used when you want one or the other to be true, but not both. This has some niche use cases, such as calculating CRCs and the like, but it's incredibly rare to need to use this with Boolean values.

In fact, I'd say it's rare enough that even I, with close to 14 years of Apex development, have probably never had a need to use `^` as a Boolean operator, although I have used it for bitfield purposes in some rare cases, such as parsing `validFor` properties on a dependent picklist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This clarifies me a lot. I have just 1 little question about it. So, isnt &= equals to x = x && y but to x = x & y instead? As from the documentation I would have assumed the first

Comment: It felt pretty great to need to use the exclusive or operator for the first time. Isn't it usually XOR not NOR?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, that's what I meant, lol.

Comment: @GabrielSerranoSalas The assignment operator versions are the non-shortcut-operator versions. The documentation is vague, but correct.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with apex, I would caution against using bitwise operators when you don't actually want to do bitwise operations. Someone might be tempted to write `if(values != null & values.size()) { ` and this will be false when values.size() is an even number in certain programming languages.

Comment: @ontrack Thankfully, in Apex, it would result in a compilation error, as you can't combine a Boolean and an Integer, unlike something like C. Still, you're right, these operators are only rarely used in practice in Apex.